# Webdav.Net Ajax File Browser: cannot connect to the webdav server in FireFox 20.0.1

Tags: ajax, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I am using the code below to display the ajax file browser control in a .Net Web app project that I run locally using the development web server on an auto assigned port.

The webdav server runs locally on IIS 7 (port 80), it is a .net app using the webdav.net server library. The security in the app is set Windows Authentication. I also allow anonymous users to the OPTIONS request.

The page works fine in IE & Chrome, however FireFox doesn't connect, it returns the message: Location ".../WebDav/" not found.

I enabled Firebug and the problem is that the Webdav server returns a 401 Unauthorized to the OPTIONS request.

Is there anything that can be done to make it work in FireFox as well?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>IT Hit AJAX File Browser</title>

<!-- Always set width and height for html and body if you would like to set width and height for Ajax File Browser control to 100% -->
<style type="text/css">
    @import "AjaxFileBrowser/themes/ih_vista/include.css";
    html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
</style>

<script src="AjaxFileBrowser/ITHitAJAXFileBrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitAjaxFileBrowser() {

        // Here we assume that your server is located on site root (http://server/) on the domain from which this page is loaded. 
        // If your WebDAV server is located on a different domain or on a different port the server must attach the Access-Control-Allow headers to server responses.
        var port = window.location.port == '' ? '' : ':' + window.location.port;
        var webDavServerPath = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + port;
        webDavServerPath = "http://localhost/WebDav";

        // Create the AJAX File Browser Settings object.
        var settings = {
            Id: 'AjaxFileBrowserContainer',     // (required) ID of the HTML control in which Ajax File Browser will be created
            Url: webDavServerPath,              // (required) the root folder to be displyed in Ajax File browser
            Style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%', // (required) always provide size of the control
            FileIconsPath: '/TestWebDavAjaxFileBrowser/AjaxFileBrowser/icons/',           // (required) path to the folder where file icons are located
            MsOfficeTemplatesPath: webDavServerPath + '/', // path to MS Office templates, always specify full path
            SelectedFolder: webDavServerPath,                        // folder to be selected, same as SetSelectedFolder call
            PluginsPath: '/TestWebDavAjaxFileBrowser/AjaxFileBrowser/plugins/'                                 // path to Java applet that opens documents directly from server
        };

        //Create control.
        var ajaxFileBrowser = new ITHit.WebDAV.Client.AjaxFileBrowser.Controller(settings);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body class="ih_vista" onload="InitAjaxFileBrowser();">
<div id="AjaxFileBrowserContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Update 1:

I tried the solution outlined for Safari here: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/programming/authentication_ssl, however it doesn't work (neither Safari nor FireFox). I am prompted for password but the options request is still Unauthorized.

I also enabled NTLM Authentication in the .Net project properties - Web tab. Still doesn't work the OPTIONS request comes back as unauthorized.

Update 2:

I got it working in FireFox when I run the client .Net app in IIS rather than the development web server (the .Net client web app and the webdav server run locally in IIS on port 80). When I run it in IIS, FireFox works but not Safari. Safari keeps prompting me for password. I am still curious to see if there is a solution when running the client app in the local development web server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <!-- 
  To support Windows Shell (Miniredirector/Web Folders) on XP and Server 2003 as well as Firefox CORS requests, OPTIONS must be 
  processed without authentication. To enable authentication of OPTIONS request, remove "allow OPTIONS" from the list below.
  -->
  <allow users="*" verbs="OPTIONS"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```